# Attribute Error: 'sage.rings.polynomial.skew_polynomial_element.SkewPolynomial_generic_de\ nse' object has no attribute 'factor'

Tags: python

While running sage Notebook:

```
R.<w>=GF(3^2)
Frob=R.frobenius_endomorphism()
S.<x>=R['x',Frob];
S
Skew Polynomial Ring in x over Finite Field in w of size 3^2 twisted by
w |--> w^3
a=x^6-1
F=a.factor(); F
```

while executing the last line getting following error:

```
Traceback (click to the left of this block for traceback)
...
AttributeError:
'sage.rings.polynomial.skew_polynomial_element.SkewPolynomial_generic_de\
nse' object has no attribute 'factor'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty straightforward. The class `SkewPolynomial_generic_dense` does not have a method called `factor()`.

You can see from the documentation [here](http://www2.math.ritsumei.ac.jp/doc/static/reference/polynomial_rings/sage/rings/polynomial/skew_polynomial_element.html#sage.rings.polynomial.skew_polynomial_element.SkewPolynomial_generic_dense) on the available methods within that class that you can use.

Can you try to set it as `F=a.factor` and see if that works?

Comment: Hey I have tried this ```F=a.factor``` but getting same error again.

Comment: @UjalaSingh Where did you find in the documentation that `factor` is a useable attribute or a method?